# Can someone share with me an article that studies the decline of by-phrases in the passive?

Tags: syntax, grammar, reference-request, corpora, passive

Can someone share with me an article that studies the decline of by-phrases in the passive? Preferably a corpus-based study, but this is not that relevant

Comment: What’s your basics for the assumption that there is such a decline to begin with?

Answer (score 4):

[This thesis](https://shareok.org/bitstream/handle/11244/7061/English%20Department_12.pdf?sequence=1) studies the history of passives and as part of the study looks at the instance of by-phrases, in the journal *American journal of botany*, grouping articles into three historical clusters – 1910's, 1960's and 2000's. The study also considers where in an article the passive appears. The frequency of by-phrases in passives decreases substantially, with 1960's frequency being about 1/3 that of 1910's; there is a small uptick in by-phrases between the 1960's and 2000's.